# Validate-content returns error for json content type Azure Api Management policies

Tags: azure, validation, content-type, azure-api-management, policies

I am using following code

```
    <validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
        <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="ignore" />
    </validate-content>
```

in api management policies but when I send the request with Content-Type of `application/json` I am getting error `Unspecified content type application/json is not allowed`

Not sure the problem or I am understanding the policy wrong.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: Could you please add an example/repro of the message that your are trying validate & making the validation fail to analyze further  & also help us whether you are doing any GET or DELETE operation ?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue and was able to find one way to reproduce and solve.

If you have an operation without any representations defined and use the validate-content policy, you will receive this error.

Simplest fix: Click on operation, under Frontend choose the form-based editor (pencil icon).  Click on the Request tab.  Under Representations, click on Add representation.  Search for "json" and choose "application/json".  Save the Frontend changes.

Now the operation and validate-content should function properly.

I hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit messy, but I `iravenscroft`s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72384536/1688639) helped me get this sorted. I just wanted to give some additional context.

I added my content type as described in the linked answer:
[image: Custom content type]

Then add your `validate-content` policy where you want it:

```xml
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="validationError">
    <content type="application/vnd.my-content-type+json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" schema-id="my-schema-id" />
</validate-content>
```

In my case `my-schema-id` is a schema uploaded on the instance level:
[image: Instance schema]

With this, validation works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `validate-content` policy is used to **validate the size or JSON schema of a request or response body against the API schema**. Except JSON, no other format is supported.

The following example shows how the JSON payload in requests and responses is validated. Messages with payloads larger than 100 KB are blocked.

```xml
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
    <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="detect" />
    <content type="application/hal+json" validate-as="json" action="detect" />
</validate-content>
```

I would suggest to read this [API Management policies to validate requests and responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validation-policies) document from Microsoft for detailed information on `validate-content` policy.

This should solve the problem you are facing. But if you still encounter the same error then raise a ticket to [Azure support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/options/).